# Symfony 3, ManyToOne relation in form

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, relational-database, symfony-3.2

I have a few Entities and I try to setup relations between users and permissions. I want to have possibility to assign group of permissions to user, so I created entity User, GroupAssociationsUser, Permissions. I though that best way is to create relation ManyToOne in GroupAssociationsUser to Users and to Permissions. Bellow you can see code of GroupAssociationsUser entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Permissions", inversedBy="group_assoc_user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="group_permissions", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
 */
private $group_permissions;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User", inversedBy="group_assoc_user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_assoc", referencedColumnName="id", nullable=FALSE)
 */
private $user_assoc;
```

Then I also created relation in User entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GroupAssociationsUser", mappedBy="user_assoc")
 */
private $group_assoc_user;


public function __construct()
{
    $this->group_assoc_user = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Finally in Permission entity:

```
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="GroupAssociationsUser", mappedBy="group_permissions")
*/
private $group_assoc_user;

public function __construct()
{
$this->group_assoc_user = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

So basically I want to have select list on my user edit page and I want to have possibility to select permission group to assign to user.

So I created form with:

```
->add('group_assoc_user', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:Permissions',
            'choice_label'=> 'group_name',
            'placeholder' => 'no rights',
        ))
```

And the problem is that no mater what I do, I have got only list of exiting permissions or if I change code to :

```
        ->add('group_assoc_user', EntityType::class, array(
            'class' => 'AppBundle:GroupAssociationsUser',
            'choice_label'=> 'Permissions.group_name',
            'placeholder' => 'no rights',
        ));
```

I have got listed only assigned permission without not assigned. What am I doing wrong?

Even if I got all permissions names how I can force doctrine to mark already assigned field?

Comment: try to use query builder  -[like this](http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#using-a-custom-query-for-the-entities)

Comment: Hi Peter, 

what exactly I should return? 
`'class' => 'AppBundle:Permissions',
'query_builder' => function (EntityRepository $er) {
     return $er->createQueryBuilder('u')
               ->orderBy('u.id', 'ASC');
    },`
Using my methods (code above), I can get  assigned field info but without unassigned. Or like in first example I can get all permissions but I have no idea how should I select selected (<option>) element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set Multiple to true.

http://symfony.com/doc/current/reference/forms/types/entity.html#multiple

```
    ->add('group_assoc_user', EntityType::class, array(
        'class' => 'AppBundle:GroupAssociationsUser',
        'choice_label'=> 'Permissions.group_name',
        'placeholder' => 'no rights',
        'multiple' => true,
    ));
```

You may also like the

```
'expanded' => true
```

option